# How do we georeference a toposheet using GCS or PCS?

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, topography, ground-control

I am new to the GIS domain. I need to georeference a toposheet, Datum - WGS84, 1:50,000 scale map. I have done the georeferencing using WGS for GCP's and then projected to WGS_94_UTM Zone 43N, using Project Tool.
Another way I followed is, using an online GCS to PCS converter and choosing those values for Ground Control Points. I would like to know which method is correct.

Comment: The map extent (graticule) have a geographic value but the map sheet is definitely not created in geographic coordinates, look in the marginalia for the projection info, it should be there, most likely a 1:50k is WGS84/UTM but could be Mercator, Lamberts, Albers etc. If you look closely at the edges you will see that they are noticeably not straight. There should be no difference with the values whichever converter you use to convert geographic to projected, though in a previous role I georeferenced scanned images using the points-in-geographic then project so I'm bias toward that method.

Comment: @MichaelStimson You are rightly skeptic. Transformation from geographic to projected coordinate system should be made after knowing the actual coordinate system and associated parameters. Directly transferring into UTM would lead to geometric discrepancies in terms of positional accuracy. In most instances, each country prefers to prepare topo sheets with their customized datum and GCPs. The absolute and relative accuracy concerns must be taken into mind.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have been doing the first step so far and I was told it is not the correct procedure. @Ben does that mean, I should never use PCS values directly for the GCPs?

Comment: @Ben, a few years ago I worked on a project of georeferencing scanned maps, all printed prior to 1984 so were guaranteed not to be WGS84 (the 84 means 1984), the images had marginalia but finding information on obscure and superseded datums and projections made the project more exciting, that truly educated me that you can't assume UTM *all* the time.. if you can't find projection information your next best guess is based on the first printing date, if it's U.S. and after 1984 then UTM is likely but still not guaranteed, each state had its own system prior and many didn't want to change.

Comment: The first method is valid but only if the map was created in WGS84/UTM Zone 43 north, the projection is applied to *flatten out* the features onto a piece of paper which is why the graticule is not straight. You plot the sheet corners in geographic coordinates then project the points into the correct projected coordinate reference system then georeference the graticule intersections to the projected points which will georeference the map face to the projected coordinate system, if you need this as a geographic representation you can warp the image but it still has to begin as projected.

Comment: @AavaniPriya it has been nicely explained by Michael Stimson, If you are confident that your input GCPs and topo sheet correspond to WGS-84 datum then, there would be no problem to transform it into destined projected coordinate system (UTM). Given that WGS-1984 datum is common to both coordinate systems.

Comment: Invariably, the topo sheets are prepared in Projected coordinate systems, so its parameters must be known prior to geo-referencing and transforming a topo sheet to other coordinate system, properly.